# Are suspend/power management problems on or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

This has been said several times already, but apparently we need to make a Meta Q explaining all the reasons why a question will be considered a Bug and hence closed as off-topic. So this is one of these questions:

Are issues likely to be a bug in the kernel or power management systems included, but not limited to questions that should get solved by applying a workaround, upgrading, downgrading, and any other act that isn't just change the configuration of a file/parameter in Ubuntu on-topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all power management questions are bugs, sometimes it's something like blacklisting a certain module or another configuration issue to get power management to work; it's the same as wireless questions.

Comment: But if the "common solutions" didn't work, then it's a bug right?

Comment: Depends, it's like wireless, hard to tell enough that a blanket policy really doesn't make sense here, and tbh, given the flood of way worse "crash" questions, I'd say save your close votes for other junk.